# How to calculate all the zeroes of $f(x) = \cos^{2}x + \sin x$ without using quadratic equations?

Tags: trigonometry

> How to calculate all the zeroes of $f(x) = \cos^{2}x + \sin x$ without using quadratic equations?

I know that I could use $\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x = 1$ and then rewrite the equation as

$$-\sin^{2}x + \sin x +1 = 0$$

Then with substitution I can calculate this as quadratic equation

$$-t^{2} + t +1 = 0$$

but I am interested if there is any easier way to calculate the zeroes?

Comment: Your method seems not hard at all; I can't imagine a significantly easier approach...

Comment: I don't believe that there is a simpler way in this case, most other trig identities yield a significantly harder equation to solve.

Comment: I see no easier method. There's no “easy” angle such that $\sin x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.